# Aspect ratio and resolution

Tags: monitors

I'm in need for a new screen. I've started looking for some screens but then I came the question: 21:9 or 1440p? After some digging around if found 2 screens i really like.

One from Lg that is 21:9 1080P and Freesync support(not that i can use it but more on that). The other screen I found was Dell ultrasharp 1440P screen. Which of the 2 is better for gaming and light programming. I will also be running a second 1080p screen of an 21" size format.

The LG 29UM67 is a 1080P 21:9 screen this means it gets a resolution of about 2560x1080. it has a 75Hz refresh rate in freesync mode which can be activated no matter what videocard you have on it. The format of the screen it 29" so its not big nor small. Without freesync the screen may get screen tearing.

The Dell Ultrasharp U2515H is a 1440P screen with an aspect ratio in about 16:9. It has a 60Hz refresh rate and a 6ms response time. the size of this screen is 25". It has problems with back light bleed.

I'm running a Gtx 970 G1 gaming, so type doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your working/gaming style I suppose.

Maybe its cause I'm older but I tend to treasure *vertical* space over horizontal space, so ultrawide displays have never appealed to me. As a replacement for *two* monitors, or as part of a *expansive* stretched workspace 21:9 might work awesome. You can dock 2-4 windows and have plenty of space without the annoying bezel. Its a bit of a niche product and prices are adjusted upwards accordingly. That said, I'm not a fan of wide screens and this is a bit of a biased opinion

On the other hand 1440p is pretty well regarded - Until recently Jeff Atwood swore by [1440p/27 inch displays that were pretty reasonably priced](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ips-lcd-revolution/), and your dell is smaller - which means better pixel pitch. Text is likely going to be sharper, backlight bleed is not that bad on quality displays (and seems to be more of a thing on IPS displays, and for gaming, its a more common aspect ratio. I've driven games at 1440p- with a gforce 660, so it would also be easy to run for gaming

Pixel pitch is a big deal. Basically the more pixels per square inch you have, the sharper a monitor is, and the easier it is to read text. I'm not *too* sure how much of an improvement it is between 1080p and 1440p, since I jumped straight to 2160p but it would likely be better to have higher resolutions

As for aspect ratio 16:9 is the standard for TVs. Its standard for most games, and [PC gamer seems to think you need additional software](http://www.pcgamer.com/219-gaming-guide-shooting-in-cinemascope/) to get things running.

So, between them? The Dell makes more sense. I'd probably also consider a few less traditional options before making my choice tho